# Swift CNContactRequestAccess threading

Tags: swift, multithreading, cncontact

I have function to get authStatus. But whenever it's .notDetermined -> I send request access to get permission.
The problem is function returns bool then asking for permission. I think the problem in threading, how can I handle it?

```
class func AskForPermission() -> Bool {
        var result = false
        let authStatus = CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts)
        switch authStatus{
        case .notDetermined:
            let contactStore = CNContactStore.init()
            contactStore.requestAccess(for: .contacts, completionHandler: { (success, nil) in
                if success {
                    result = true
                } else {
                    result = false
                }
            })
        case .authorized:
            result = true
        default:
            result = false
        }

        print(result)
        return result
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Closer instead of returning a boolean value

```
'func AskForPermission(completionHandler:@escaping (_ autherizationStatus:Bool)->Void){
    let authStatus = CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts)
    switch authStatus{
    case .notDetermined:
        let contactStore = CNContactStore.init()
        contactStore.requestAccess(for: .contacts, completionHandler: { (success, nil) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if success {
                    completionHandler(true)
                } else {
                    completionHandler(false)
                }
            }
        })
    case .authorized:
        completionHandler(false)
        break
    default:
        completionHandler(false)
       break
    }
}'
```

call this Function like this

```
'AskForPermission(completionHandler: { (isAuthorized) in
                if isAuthorized{
                    // Do your Work here....
                }
            })'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How can i use this function? For example `if !AskForPermission() { return nil }`

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. I need to take look into closures